# check if href has only # to change cursor with css

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a link in breadcrumb `Home> Media > News`
`Home` is linked to Home, Media is not a page but just a parent category which has sub page such as News , Gallery etc...

so in breadcrumb since Media is just a parent category but not an actual page i want cursor to be pointer but not hand.

Below code for example which is is jQuery changes the cursor to pointer and if i test with color then it change color to green for first two item.

Can i achive same with CSS or how i can correct this using jquery

```
<ul class="breadcrumb">
  <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Media</a></li>
  <li class="active"> News</li>
</ul> 

$('a[href*="#"]').each(function() {
    $(".breadcrumb > li > a").css('color','green');
    //$(".breadcrumb > li > a").css('cursor','pointer');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lc5ywaq2/2/

Comment: `$(".breadcrumb > li > a")` selects ALL your anchors ....` this` inside the `each` is the current element, so you'll want `$(this).whatever`

Comment: i tried but same result

Comment: no it isn't the same result at all - http://jsfiddle.net/2b30owu6/ - of course, your code here and the code in your fiddle are different ... you try to change the cursor to a pointer ... which it already is ... so you'll see no change

Comment: did you perhaps want `.css('cursor','default')` to indicate it's not a link to a different page?

Comment: @JaromandaX, I tried same it was not working, but your code works..

Comment: yes, so you must've done something else wrong :p perhaps in your real code, you're running the code before the elements exist

Comment: @JaromandaX, my main question was if we can do same just with CSS?

Comment: oh, of course you can `.breadcrumb li a[href^="#"] { /* style goes here */}`

Comment: @JaromandaX, Yes it works can you put this as answer so that i can mark it as correct answer. to help others also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your CSS currently has

```
.breadcrumb li a { 
   color:red;
}
```

You'll want to add

```
.breadcrumb li a[href^="#"] { 
   color:green;
}
```

note: your jquery looks for `#` anywhere in the href, but you should be looking for `#` as the first character, that's what `[href^="#"]` does as opposed to `[href*="#"]`